# how to set angular2 form value from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Basically, in this form. I have onsubmit function which will save fromDate and toDate in LocalStorage. In component.ts, I was trying to define a function which will pull date data from local storage and set the form value. And it seems that setting the form value is NOT working for me. Here is the code:

in component.ts

```
@ViewChild ( 'formRef' ) form;

this.form.fromDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("startDate")).getDate()  ;
this.form.toDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("endDate")).getDate()  ;
```

component.html

```
<input name="fromDate" id="fromDate" type="date"   [(ngModel)]="fromDate"

                                               #fromDate ="ngModel"
                                               required>

<input name="toDate " id="toDate " type="date"   [(ngModel)]="toDate "

                                               #toDate ="ngModel"
                                               required>
```

Comment: I verified that LocalStorage has correct value. the question here is how can i update form values, in browser console, this.fromDate = localStorage.getItem("endDate") works. But in my TS code, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.form.controls['fromDate'].updateValueAndValidity(new Date(localStorage.getItem("startDate")).getDate().toDateString());
this.form.controls['toDate'].updateValueAndValidity(new Date(localStorage.getItem("endDate")).getDate().toDateString());
```

By default, it will also update the value and validity of its ancestors.

```
updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
}): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fromDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("startDate")).getDate()  ;
var toDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("endDate")).getDate()  ;

this.form.get('formDate').updateValueAndValidity(fromDate);
this.form.get('toDate').updateValueAndValidity(toDate);
```

or if `updateValueAndValidity` doesn't support to pass a `Date` object (don't remember if it does):

```
this.form.get('formDate').updateValueAndValidity(fromDate.toDateString());
this.form.get(toDate').updateValueAndValidity(toDate.toDateString());
```